# Black Hat Python proxy tool no data

Tags: python, proxy

I recently bought the book *Black Hat Python, 2nd Edition*, by Justin Seitz, which seems to be a very good book about networking and all that (i am writing my code on Kali Linux)

I have a problem on the TCP Proxy Tool on chapter 2 :

Here is the code :

```
import sys
import socket
import threading

HEX_FILTER = ''.join(
    [(len(repr(chr(i))) == 3) and chr(i) or '.' for i in range(256)])

def hexdump(src, length = 16, show = True):
# basically translates hexadecimal characters to readable ones
    if isinstance(src, bytes):
        src = src.decode()

    results = list()
    for i in range(0, len(src), length):
        word = str(src[i:i+length])

        printable = word.translate(HEX_FILTER)
        hexa = ' '.join(['{ord(c):02X}' for c in word])
        hexwidth = length*3
        results.append('{i:04x}  {hexa:<{hexwidth}}  {printable}')
    if show :
        for line in results :
            print(line)
    else :
        return results

def receive_from(connection): 
    buffer = b""
    connection.settimeout(10)
    try :
        while True :
            data = connection.recvfrom(4096)
            if not data :
                break
            buffer += data
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    return buffer

def request_handler(buffer):
    # perform packet modifications
    return buffer

def response_handler(buffer):
    # perform packet modifications
    return buffer

def proxy_handler(client_socket, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first):
    remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    remote_socket.connect((remote_host, remote_port))

    if receive_first :
# Check for any data to receive before
going into the main loop (i guess)
        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)
        hexdump(remote_buffer)
                                                                                    
    remote_buffer = response_handler(remote_buffer)                                 
    if len(remote_buffer):                                                          
        print("[<==] Sending %d bytes to localhost." % len(remote_buffer))  
        client_socket.send(remote_buffer)                               
                                                                                    
    while True :                                                                    # Start the loop
        local_buffer = receive_from(client_socket)                                  
        if len(local_buffer):               
            line = "[==>] Received %d bytes from localhost." % len(local_buffer)
            print(line)                                                         
            hexdump(local_buffer)                                                   

            local_buffer = request_handler(local_buffer)                            
            remote_socket.send(local_buffer)                                        
            print("[==>] Sent to remote.")
                                                                                                                                
        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)                                                                 
        if len(remote_buffer):                                                                                                  
            print("[==>] Received %d bytes from remote." % len(remote_buffer))                              
            hexdump(remote_buffer)                                                                                              
                                                                                                            
            remote_buffer=response_handler(remote_buffer)                                                       
            client_socket.send(remote_buffer)                                       
            print("[<==] Sent to localhost.")
                                                                                    
        if not len(local_buffer) or not len(remote_buffer):
# If no data is passed, close the sockets and breaks the loop
            client_socket.close()                                                   
            remote_socket.close()                                                   
            print("[*] No more data. Closing connections. See you later !")
            break

def server_loop(local_host, local_port, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first):
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                      

    try :
        server.bind((local_host, local_port))                                       # Bind the local host and the local port
    except Exception as e:
        print('Problem on bind : %r' %e)
                                                                                    # If an error occurs, prints a
        print("[!] Failed to listen on %s:%d" % (local_host, local_port))
        print("[!] Check for other listening sockets or correct permissions.")
        sys.exit(0)

    print("[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (local_host, local_port))
    server.listen(5)
    while True :
        client_socket, addr = server.accept()                                        
        # print out the local connection information

        line = "> Received incoming connection from %s:%d" % (addr[0], addr[1])
        print(line)
        # start a thread to talk to the remote host
        proxy_thread = threading.Thread(
            target = proxy_handler,
            args=(client_socket,remote_host,
                remote_port, receive_first))
        proxy_thread.start()

def main():
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) != 5:
        print("Usage: ./proxy.py [localhost] [localport]")
        print("[remotehost] [remoteport] [receive_first]")
        print("Example : ./proxy.py 127.0.0.1 9000 192.168.56.1 9000 True")
        sys.exit(0)
    loca l_host = sys.argv[1]
    local_port = int(sys.argv[2])

    remote_host = sys.argv[3]
    remote_port = int(sys.argv[4])

    receive_first = sys.argv[5]

    if "True" in receive_first:
        receive_first = True
    else :
        receive_first = False

    server_loop(local_host, local_port,
        remote_host, remote_port, receive_first)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(sorry, i had a bit of a trouble formatting it and it's quite long)

Now, normally, i just need to open 2 terminals and run the code with the command line :

```
sudo python proxy.py 127.0.0.1 21 ftp.dlptest.com 21 True
```

in one terminal, and :

```
ftp 127.0.0.1 21
```

in the other one.

My code seems to be working fine, except that... I receive no data. I tried different ftp servers (notice that i don't use the one quoted in the book), but it still doesn't work. It just says :

```
[*] Listening on 127.0.0.1
> Received incoming connection from 127.0.0.1:55856
```

but it doesn't actually displays anything until the connexion times out or that i stop the command with Ctrl + C.

I know this question has already been asked, but they don't resolve my problem.

Please tell me if i forgot a line of code (for example the one that prints the data on the screen lol) or did anything wrong :)

Comment: What debugging have you done so far? What's the last code that's actually being executed? Is proxy_handler running at all? Also, I'm not sure if `proxy_thread.start()` is a blocking call or not - you have it in a `while True` loop, so there's nothing stopping it from getting called multiple times from what I can see.

Comment: Capturing a generic exception and ignoring it, is a sure way to miss unintended exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

one the hexa variable you need to put and f'{ord(c):02x}' because you just have a string and not using the 'c' variable from the list comprehension. That's a small typo you missed fix that and try the whole process again.

```
    hexa = ' '.join([f'{ord(c):02X}' for c in word])

The f should be here ^
```

Comment: How does this solve his problem of receiving data?